# How to save and execute a stored procedure in cosmos db through azure portal?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azureportal, azure-cosmosdb

I tried to do this from the `Script Explorer`->`Stored Procedure` view, but when I use the button **Save & Execute** there, it only gives results in the following error message:

> Failed to save the script
>
> Database Account: myaccountname, Script: HelloWorld, Message: {"code":500,"body":"{\"message\":\"An error has
>   occurred.\"}"}

And the textbox under `Results` is unchanged.

Below is a screenshot of how it looks in azure portal:
[image: Azure portal does not Save and Execute Stored Procedure]

Comment: Is that a Partitioned collection?

Comment: That collection is not partitioned.

Answer (score 2):

@MichaelRätzel: I have just written a very simple CosmosDB Script and run it on Azure Portal.

```
function TestSample() {
    getContext().getResponse().setBody("Hello World");
}
```

And here is my result:

[image: Azure Portal screenshot of succesful save]

I got the same problem with you about the `Failed to save the stored procedure`. What I did to solve that problem is:

1. `Save` the Stored Procedure first
2. Left-click to the current SP on the left column
3. `Save & Execute` the SP

I think this is a technical issue of Azure Portal. Try this and tell me the result.

Comment: I tried it as you suggested. Here is what I observed: Saving worked, despite an error message. Then I used the `Save & Execute` button: A new error message was displayed (`Failed to save the script`) and the textbox under `Results` remained empty. So this approach did not solve the problem of executing the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Save & Execute is disable, do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test this function on Azure Portal, you can delete the parameter "prefix" and add a variable name "prefix" to your stored procedure.

The reason of this error is this function needs data from outside (via parameter), and you don't provide it on Azure Portal.

```
function upsertFans() {
    var prefix = "";
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT * FROM root r',
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
            // else take 1st element from feed
            if (!feed || !feed.length) 
                getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
            else
                getContext().getResponse().setBody(prefix + JSON.stringify(feed[0]));
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Comment: This approach does not seem to work. I have tried to `Save & Execute` after deleting the parameter, but still got the error message: `Failed to save the script`

Comment: @MichaelRätzel: Hmm... Can you "Save" the script only? I have just updated my script above (I remove some characters of markdown in my code), you can copy my code and try "Save & Execute". If you still cannot run it, tell me.

Comment: I tested it again with your code, this is the result: While the `Failed to save the stored procedure` error message still appeared, the script was actually saved. The saved stored proceduce became visible after manually refreshing the view. So saving worked. What I still don't know is how to execute the stored procedure from azure portal. The textbox under `Results` is still empty. But I would expect the stored procedure to output something with the given code.

Comment: When I create and save a sproc, the Save and Execute button is never enabled no matter what I do. Not sure how to execute from portal. Looks like I am going to have to write code to do this.